# Returning struct with vector

Tags: rust

I just began learning Rust and doing some exercises.
Here I'm trying to return the next permutation. But at the end of the `next()` method it seems to return the wrong vector in the struct.

```
pub struct Permutation {
    p : Vec<u8>,
}

impl Permutation{
    pub fn new(length: u8) -> Permutation {
        let mut p :Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        for i in 1..length+1 {
            p.push(i as u8);
        }
        Permutation { p }
    }

    pub fn create(this: Vec<u8>) -> Permutation {
        Permutation { p:this }
    }

    pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Permutation> {
        let mut pivot :usize = self.p.len() + 1;
        for i in (1..self.p.len()).rev() {
            if self.p[i-1] < self.p[i] {
                pivot = i-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if pivot == self.p.len() + 1 {
            return None;
        }
        let mut swap :usize = pivot + 1;
        for i in pivot+1..self.p.len() {
            if self.p[i] > self.p[pivot] && self.p[i] < self.p[swap] {
                swap = i;
            }
        }
        let temp = self.p[swap];
        self.p[swap] = self.p[pivot];
        self.p[pivot] = temp;
        pivot += 1;
        let mut new_perm :Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..pivot {
            new_perm.push(self.p[i]);
        }
        for i in (pivot..self.p.len()).rev() {
            new_perm.push(self.p[i]);
        }
        // Debug
        // for e in &new_perm {
        //    println!("{}", e);
        //}
        return Some(Permutation{ p: new_perm })
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the println I can see that the `new_perm` vector is correct, but I seem to be getting the `self.p` vector returned.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If I create a new Permutation with length 4 and execute the next method twice i would expect the `1,3,2,4` but I'm getting `1,3,4,2`

Comment: [It works for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a6beb610d92c8c381a7904a195a270a). Maybe you printed the `Permutation` itself and not the returned value?